# Type mismatch if Number provided where string is required - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

If the value in the "ComboBox1.Value" is a number there is a Run-Time error '13' : Type Mismatch

I have already used Cstr() to convert it to string but still shows error

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim WS As Worksheet, NROW As Variant
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ClientList")
Dim Q As Integer

NROW = Application.Match(ComboBox1.Value, WS.Range("A:A"), 0)
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & NROW).Select
    Q = MsgBox("Do you want to delete this record", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)

    If Q = vbYes Then
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
        MsgBox "RECORD DELETED"
    Else
        'do nothing
    End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't find CStr anywhere in the code. In which line does the error occur? Is ComboBox1 on a form or on a worksheet? Why is NROW declared as Variant instead of Long?

Comment: @VBasic2008 I used Cstr() earlier but it did not solve my problem so i removed it.ComboBox1 is on Form, Dont know abt the declaration for NROW, i might have changes it a couple of times to find the solution. it was a "String" earlier

Comment: My code containing the WorksheetFunction version of Match will allow numbers. But the most important flaw was that you had no error handling in case a value wasn't found. Remember in Excel you use =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(whatever)),"",MATCH(whatever)). You should try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## WorksheetFunction

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Dim WS As Worksheet, NROW As Long
  Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ClientList")
  Dim Q As Integer

  If IsError(WorksheetFunction.Match(ComboBox1.Value, WS.Range("A:A"), 0)) _
          Then Exit Sub
  NROW = WorksheetFunction.Match(ComboBox1.Value, WS.Range("A:A"), 0)

  Q = MsgBox("Do you want to delete this record", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
  If Q = vbYes Then
      ActiveSheet.Range("A" & NROW).EntireRow.Delete
      MsgBox "RECORD DELETED"
    'Else
      ' do nothing
  End If

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It Works . Thanks A lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing error handling in case `Application.Match` can't find the value in the list. Also, there is no need to select rows in order to delete them.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim WS As Worksheet, NROW As Long
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ClientList")
Dim Q As Integer

If Not IsError(Application.Match(ComboBox1.Value, WS.Range("A:A"), 0)) Then

    Q = MsgBox("Do you want to delete this record", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)

    If Q = vbYes Then
        NROW = Application.Match(ComboBox1.Value, WS.Range("A:A"), 0)
        WS.Range("A" & NROW).EntireRow.Delete
        MsgBox "RECORD DELETED"
    Else
        'do nothing
    End If
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Now it is not showing error but also does nothing when a "Number" is selected from the Combobox List

Comment: @DipeshVora check if there are spaces or difference in format

Comment: Thanks . I will go with code given by @vbasic2008 as it does what is required